# How to pass parameters with redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga

as an exercise for react-native & redux-saga, I am trying to develop a little Weather-Application.

While fetching and presenting the data works just fine, I somehow struggle to pass a parameter from a TextInput to the final API call.

The goal for now is just to pass the cityName String to the fetchWeather function inside api.js and console.log it.

Starting by `props.requestWeather(cityName)` inside Main.js

I tried various things to pass the cityName via action and saga to the apiCall, only making me realize, that i was more guessing then anything else. Sadly the following research was not successful as well and so here we are.

Any ideas on how to pass the String as a parameter and/or general criticism about the following redux setup would be highly appreciated!

Dave

Main.js

```js
//[...] setCity Name to TextInput component
const [cityName, setCityName] = useState('')   
// [...] calling the action (inside onClickHandler)
props.requestWeather() 
//[...] 
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    weatherData: state.weatherData
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
    bindActionCreators({ requestWeather }, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

action.js

```js
export const REQUEST_WEATHER = "REQUEST_WEATHER"
export const RECEIVE_WEATHER = "RECEIVE_WEATHER"

export const requestWeather = () => ({ type: REQUEST_WEATHER })
export const receiveWeather = weatherData => ({ type: RECEIVE_WEATHER, weatherData })
```

sagas.js

```js
function* getWeather(action) {
  try {
    const weatherData = yield call(fetchWeather);
    yield put(receiveWeather(weatherData));
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

    
function* watchAll() {
  yield all([
    //[...]
    takeLatest(REQUEST_WEATHER, getWeather),
  ]);
}
export default watchAll;
```

api.js

```js
export const fetchWeather = async () => {
  const APPID = process.env.WEATHER_API_KEY;

  try {
    let weatherData = [];
    const weather1Promise = axios(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Rom&APPID=" + APPID
    );
    //[...]
    const [weather1, weather2, weather3] = await Promise.all([
      weather1Promise,
      weather2Promise,
      weather3Promise,
    ]);
    weatherData.push(weather1.data, weather2.data, weather3.data);
    return weatherData;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all you need to modify your action to accept `cityName`:

```js
export const requestWeather = (cityName) => ({ type: REQUEST_WEATHER, cityName });
```

Then inside sagas:

```js
const weatherData = yield call(fetchWeather, action.cityName);
```

...and finally inside request:

```js
export const fetchWeather = async (cityName) => {
  console.log(cityName); // will log entered city name
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much kind user! The 'action.' before cityName inside the sagas was exactly what i needed!     export const requestWeather = cityName => ({ type: REQUEST_WEATHER, cityName });;  just to round it up i think I need to pass cityName as a param in the action ass well.

Answer (score 0):

**if you are using Axios with Redux-Saga in React Application this information with sample code should be useful**

In Redux saga, if you want to send AJAX request is better to use `call` method (built-in saga) instead of regular usage of Axios method like `axios.get()`

> REDUX-SAGA `call` method

1- First Argument: pass your AJAX lib handler, for example `call(Axios)` and in second arument you have to pass `options[]` for your request

```js
const baseApiUri = process.env.BASE_API || 'http://localhost:3030/v1';
const jwtToken = localStorage.getItem('INTERVIEW-TOKEN');

const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseApiUri,
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: {
    authorization: jwtToken,
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});


// your reqest options
const options = {
      method: 'post',
      url: ''localhost/3030,
      data: { name: 'hamid' },
}


// send request with SAGA
const user = yield call(API, options);



// send a request with Axios

const user = await API(options);

// or

const user = await axios.post(options)
```